# Data structures in spreadsheets appropriate here?

Tags: discussion

I'm considering re-inventing the spreadsheet interface.

The problem with current spreadsheet tech is that the formula is in the cell.  This makes it difficult to troubleshoot and maintain spreadsheets.

I'm working on the design of an interface and a formula syntax that separates formulas from cell locations, and removes row:column notation from formulas.  Every thing is a named range.

Is this the right SE for this?  Is any SE?  (I have doubts, as it seems to me that this will be more discussion and less answer oriented.)

If UISE isn't the right place, what site would be?

Comment: I think so, this is the kind of question I would expect to come across in the main UXSE forum.